# What is the proper way to "patch" a node_modules module?

Tags: node.js, npm, patch

Say I have a Node.js app, lets call it `patched-app`. This app is a simple app that uses [prompt-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync) to ask for user input and then does something with it.

So we create a folder `patched-app` and initialize it with `npm init`. We then run `npm i prompt-sync` and create a new file called `index.js` where my code would be. To make things a little bit more interesting, I will also create a git repository here and this is the result:

```
+---patched-app
|   |   .gitattributes
|   |   .gitattributes
|   |   .gitignore
|   |   index.js
|   |   package-lock.json
|   |   package.json
|   |   
|   +---node_modules
|   |   |   .package-lock.json
|   |   |   
|   |   +---ansi-regex
|   |   |       index.js
|   |   |       license
|   |   |       package.json
|   |   |       readme.md
|   |   |       
|   |   +---prompt-sync
|   |   |       index.js
|   |   |       LICENSE
|   |   |       package.json
|   |   |       README.md
|   |   |       test.js
|   |   |       
|   |   \---strip-ansi
|   |           index.d.ts
|   |           index.js
|   |           license
|   |           package.json
|   |           readme.md
|   \---.git
|      <<git stuff>>
```

Now the issue here is that I don't like something with this `prompt-sync` package and so I want to edit `node_modules/prompt-sync/index.js` and change it to my liking. I don't necessarily want to create a whole new module such as `prompt-sync-swiffy` (or do I?), as my changes are small enough so I don't have to download any new packages for `prompt-sync`, so I'm good with the existing dependencies of `ansi-regex` and `strip-ansi`.

I could just open up `node_modules/prompt-sync/index.js`, edit it and be done - and that's what I have pretty much been doing thus far because I don't know any better. I have recognized at least three major issues with this though:

- I cannot update `prompt-sync` anymore or I might **lose** the changes I made (losing !== just breaking my patched changes)
- I cannot basically run any package commands, such as `npm audit fix` etc, as those might also overwrite my changes
- This doesn't work at all, if I want to have my project in a git repository, because I will obviously add `node_modules` to `.gitignore` and if anyone were to pull my repository and run `npm install`, it would install `prompt-sync` without my changes

I also don't necessarily want to fork `prompt-sync` and / or create a new "official" NPM package. What I want is a method that allows me or anyone else to run `npm install` normally, while somehow keeping my patches to modules local e.g. have a `module_patches` folder which isn't ignored by the repository.

It is OK if a newer version of `prompt-sync` breaks my patch. That would be on me to update the patch or use a locked in version of `prompt-sync`.

So what are my options?

Comment: Hey just patch it and keep a copy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A nice way to patch NPM packages is using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). It will automatically create patch files of your changes and apply them in postinstall hook.

Comment: Well that's funny, this is exactly 100% what I was looking for! It makes separate .patch-files, auto-applies them, works with git-repositories and I can target exact packages and even package version with this. Excellent work, thanks for finding this for me!

Comment: why haven't I found this 2 years earlier?

Answer (score 0):

## Patch a "node_modules" (Node.js) module

Patch-package lets app authors instantly make and keep fixes to npm dependencies. It's a vital band-aid for those of us living on the bleeding edge.

### Process

#### Fix a bug in one of your dependencies

**MODEL**

```
nano "node_modules/<PACKAGE_NAME>/some_file.js"
```

#### Run patch-package to create a "*.patch" (in "patches" folder) file

**MODEL**

```
npx patch-package "<PACKAGE_NAME>"
```

### Required settings/resources in your "package.json"

For patches to be applied during installation, these settings/resources are necessary in your "package.json".

```
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    [...]
    "patch-package": "X.X.X",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "X.X.X",
    [...]
  },
  [...]
  "scripts": {
    [...]
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  [...]
```

Ref(s):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72826192/3223785
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

**Thanks!**